# Building sqlite under windows with soundex function

Tags: windows, sqlite, cl, soundex

I am trying to build sqlite under windows with soundex funtion, while build succeeds, i still don't get soundex functionality. i couldn't figure out where is the error.

```
cl -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=0 -DSQLITE_SOUNDEX sqlite3.c -link -dll -out:sqlite3.dll
```

outputs:

```
/out:sqlite3.exe
-dll
-out:sqlite3.dll
sqlite3.obj
```

When i try newly build dll

```
C:\sqlite\sqlite-amalgamation-3250200>sqlite3.exe
SQLite version 3.25.2 2018-09-25 19:08:10
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> SELECT SOUNDEX("John"), SOUNDEX("Joahn");
Error: no such function: SOUNDEX
sqlite>
```

For ubuntu its very clear how to compile with parameters but for windows i couldn't find what is the way to pass DSQLITE_SOUNDEX correctly.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `/DSQLITE_SOUNDEX=1`?

Comment: And make sure you're compiling sqlite3.exe with the same options - it doesn't use a dll, it includes a static sqlite3.obj.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to compile  sqlite3.exe